# How to specify multiple parameters in link

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this in my router.ex:

```
resources "/games", GamesController do
  get "/scores/:student_id", GameScoreController, :new
  post "/scores/:student_id", GameScoreController, :create
end
```

Now I am calling this with:

```
link(student.name, to: game_game_score_path(@conn, :new, @game, student_id: student))
```

But that creates a link: /games/1/scores?student_id=1 instead of /games/1/scores/1.

How do I call link so it generates the correct url?

Oh, and is there a way to get rid of the double game in the helper?
I tried adding as: :game_score, but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the route as:

```
resources "/games", GameController do
  get "/scores/:student_id", ScoreController, :new
  post "/scores/:student_id", ScoreController, :create
end
```

Note everything in Phoenix is singular, including the controller name. The URL is plural but it is external, it doesn't dictate how your code is organized.

And the URL helper:

```
link(student.name, to: game_game_score_path(@conn, :new, @game, student))
```

If you want the controller to be `GameScoreController`, you can pass the `:as` option to customize the generated helper. More info in the Phoenix docs: http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#resources/4

Comment: I don't know what I changed, except adding a 3rd route, but the link suddenly works. My controller is GameScoreController, I needed to use as: :score, and now that works too. Perfect! Thanks!